# I am not getting the exact coordinates

Tags: android

I have a relative layout which i am populating with imageview via the onLongClick, my problem is I am not getting the exact coordinates, everytime I populate with an imageview it is placed at a point where my finger is not at, I feel I am missing out something looking at other apps that do the same below if my code:

this method generates an imageview randomly.

```
private ImageView generateImageView()
{
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    imageView.setLayoutParams( params );
    this.parentLayout.addView(imageView);

    return imageView;

}
```

This method moves the imageview to the location provided by the coordinates in the ontouch

```
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    this.absoluteClickedX = (int) motionEvent.getRawX();
    Log.d("X Coordinate", ""+this.absoluteClickedX);
    this.absoluteClickedY = (int) motionEvent.getRawY();
    Log.d("Y Coordinate", ""+this.absoluteClickedY);

    return false;
}
```

And finally this methods sets the imageview to its new location

```
   private void setAbsoluteLocation(ImageView imageView, int x, int y)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams alp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();

    alp.leftMargin = x-50;
    alp.topMargin = y-50;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(alp);

}
```

Where I am going wrong? and sorry for my bad English

Comment: "I am not getting the exact coordinates" -- please edit your question to explain **completely** what you mean by this and how you have determined that you are "not getting the exact coordinates".

Comment: I have edited it and thanks for the heads up